# class.upload.php: ¿cómo obtener el resultado de una conversión de VARIAS imágenes para después enviarlas por correo?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas noches y feliz navidad a todos.

Resulta que me encuentro haciendo un pequeño formulario de registro, donde los usuarios tiene que enviar 4 imágenes junto con otros campos de texto.

He ocupado el script de `class.upload.php` (https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) donde me permite bajar el peso de las imágenes que subirán los usuarios. He podido obtener una conversión exitosa de todos los archivos, el tema viene con la siguiente parte del pequeño proyecto que estoy realizando, que es una vez que se han convertido, ¿cómo es que obtengo el resultado de este array de imágenes en una variable para posteriormente enviarlas por correo?

Para el envío de correos ocupo phpMailer, lo he ocupado muchas veces pero solamente con envío de texto y con envío de una sola imagen; nunca he pasado varias imágenes mediante un array.

El envío de los datos que voy a hacer vía mail lo hago creando una función para no tener todo el código en un solo doc.

```
<?php
require_once('../db.php');
require_once('../conexion.php');
require_once('../correos.php');
include('../vendor/class-upload/class.upload.php');

use Verot\Upload\Upload;

$patrocinador = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["patrocinador"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE curp = '" . $patrocinador . "'");
$rw = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$id_patrocinador = $rw['id'];
$name = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$a_p = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["a_p"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$a_m = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["a_m"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$curp = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["curp"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$telefono = intval($_POST["telefono"]);
$correo = strtolower(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["correo"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$imagenes = $_FILES['imagen'];

/******COMPRIMIR IMAGEN*********/
$files = array();
foreach ($imagenes as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
            $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}
// Ahora podemos recorrer cada $_FILES($files) y pasar cada elemento a la clase Upload
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // Instanciamos la clase para cada elemento de $ file
    $handle = new Upload($file);
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        $handle->file_new_name_body   = 'new_document';
        $handle->image_resize = true;
        $handle->image_x = $handle->image_src_x / 2;
        $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
        $handle->jpeg_quality = 50;
/*      $handle->png_compression = 9; */
        $handle->process('../images/documentos/');
/*      $handle->file_dst_pathname; */
        if ($handle->processed) {
            /* echo 'image resized'; */
            $handle->clean();
        } else {
            echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
        }
    }
}
/****** FIN COMPRIMIR IMAGEN*********/

$sql = "INSERT INTO pre_registro (patrocinador,name,a_p,a_m,curp,telefono,correo) 
VALUES ('$id_patrocinador','$name','$a_p','$a_m','$curp','$telefono','$correo');";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($resultado) {
    
    correosoldevi($patrocinador, $name, $a_p, $a_m, $curp, $telefono, $AquiIrianLasImagenesParaEnviar);

} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Hubo un error, favor de intentarlo en unos minutos');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar o si no fui muy claro, GRACIAS. (Las imágenes no las inserto a la BD)